# Best way to run multiple HystrixCommand in parallel

Tags: java, future, hystrix

I have a `List<HystrixCommand<?>>> commands`, what is the best way to execute these commands and collect the results such that the commands run in parallel?

---

I have tried something like this:

```
List<Future<?>> futures = commands.stream()
    .map(HystrixCommand::queue)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<?> results = futures.stream()
    .map(Future::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Does this run the commands in parallel?

I.e. when calling `HystrixCommand.queue()`  followed by `Future.get()` on the same thread, the `.get()` call does not block on some command and delay the other commands?

I ask because I couldn't find any documentation for this.

---

I have also looked at `HystrixCollapser`, but this still requires creating and running the individual commands (like above) in the `createCommand` method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have investigated this and figured it out... by creating some simple examples rather than debugging production code...

---

My initial code was correct:

```
List<Request> requests = ...; // some expensive requests
List<HystrixCommand<?>>> commands = getCommands(requests);

List<Future<?>> futures = commands.stream()
    .map(HystrixCommand::queue)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<?> results = futures.stream()
    .map(Future::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The commands do indeed run in parallel.

The `.get()` method does block, but since all the commands have been queued (prior to any `.get()` call) they are all running (or queued to run).

Say the second command is faster to completion than the first. The first `.get()` will block, but when it eventually returns, the second `.get()` call will return immediately, as the second command was able to complete while the first command was blocking. (Assuming core size >=2.)

---

In terms of `HystrixCollapser`, I misunderstood the API. `HystrixCollapser` is used to combine many `HystrixCollapser` instances into one `HystrixCommand` not the other way around. So I had to modify my code to wrap my requests with `HystrixCollapser`rather than `HystrixCommand`:

```
List<Request> requests = ...; // some expensive requests
List<HystrixCollapser<?>>> commands = getCommands(requests);

HystrixRequestContext context = HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext();
try {
    List<Future<?>> futures = commands.stream()
      .map(HystrixCollapser::queue)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<?> results = futures.stream()
      .map(Future::get)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
} finally {
  context.shutdown();
}
```

---

[JMH benchmarks and full example source here](https://github.com/wilmol/Java-Benchmarks/blob/master/hystrix/src/main/java/com/wilmol/hystrix/BatchingRequests.java)